# Debian: Unable to use mono (missing mscorlib.dll)

Tags: linux, debian, mono-framework

I've been trying over the months to use mono on Debian 7 x64 but try after try it never works. I've installed it on several different machines only to come to the same end:

```
mono program.exe
The assembly mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be loaded.
It should have been installed in the `/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll' directory.
```

I've tried to install it on every way possible. In fact the only time I could see mono working was on a Ubuntu host but changing distro is not a option now. I dont believe this is a issue with my program because it worked on ubuntu.

This is how I proceed to install it (worked on Ubuntu, on debian never)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpng3 libpng3-dev libtool libtiff4 libtiff4-dev libexif12 libexif-dev libgif4 libgif-dev libpango1.0-dev libatk1.0-dev bison automake autoconf make gcc gtk-sharp2 build-essential xorg-dev libfreetype6 libfontconfig libfontconfig-dev gettext libglib2.0-dev git mono-complete libjpeg-dev
git clone git://github.com/mono/mono.git
cd mono
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

mono -V

```
Mono JIT compiler version 3.4.1 (master/683527c Sun Apr 20 04:18:47 CEST 2014)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen
```

I've searched this problem extensively and no proposed solution worked.
I wonder how can anyone get mono to work on debian ?

Thanks.

Comment: Small dump question: Are you sure the application you try to run is a CLI application?

Comment: Yes it is. I was able to run it on Ubuntu, and several other people seem to run it just fine. Its just this "thing" with debian that makes no sense.

Comment: Okay. Have you checked the "missing" dll? is it there and can't be loaded for some reason or is it really missing? In this case I would try to download it manually.

Comment: /usr/local/lib/mono does not exist. It makes me think it is probably somewhere else and pointing to the wrong path. And I'm not sure where I should download it from

Comment: Mhm this is possible of course. Can't you find any mono-lib folders? For me it's under /usr/lib/. What about checking the scripts? What does this autogen.sh do? I suppose it's setting up a makefile your you.. What is then written in this makefile? Are the folders there correct? Compare the paths there and look if files have been copied correctly.

Comment: It found mine under /usr/lib/ as well but no 4.5 subdir, only for 2.0, 3.5 and 4.0. I copied /usr/lib/ to /usr/local/lib/mono. After trying to run I now get a "Native stacktrace (...) Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code (...)". I suspected that the curlpit is "--prefix=/usr/local". I reinstalled using "--prefix=/usr". Same result.

Comment: Okay. Funny thing is i got the same error yesterday. Just a question: Is the program you try to run a .NET windows application? It was the case for me. My missing mscorlib.dll should be in the 2.0 folder, i only had a 4.0 one. symlinked this one to 2.0 (just to try :D) - bunch of errors. I had to run the application through wine, with the dotnet extension. Maybe this could be the issue for you too?

Answer (score 2):

The `libmono-corlib4.5-cil` package contains `/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll`.

I think you should be able to just install everything from packages; there should be no need to compile mono from source and install it manually under /usr/local:

`sudo apt-get install mono-complete libmono-corlib4.5-cil`

And be sure you remove your manually installed mono from /usr/local.

Comment: Not useful if you're on a platform where you cannot use source packages. Debian PowerPC has broken mono packages right now.